# Библиотека Eel и Pyinstaller не открывает страницу

Tags: python, html

Написал сайт, все стили, картинки и страницы в одной папке web, рядом с ней main.py
В нем код, который запускает этот сайт.

```
import eel
eel.init("web")
eel.start('windows_game_1.html', mode="chrome", port=0 , size=(1280,512))
```

Все работает до того момента, как я компилирую в exe файл, используя pyinstaller. После компиляции, запускаю и выдает ошибку 404. Что делать, как все же запустить его?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, папка web не находится там же, где этот exe файл.
Попробуйте переметить exe'шник туда, где лежит папка web.

Answer (score 0):

Папку web скопируй и вставь в созданную после pyinstaller'ом папку dist, внутри неё есть папка main и вот туда вставляй папку web